# keep getting undefined data outside of subscribe() in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to fetch data using angular, then assign the data to the newUser variable to use it outside subscribe. However, when I use this variable outside of subscribe, I get undefined. I know this because Subscribe(), will execute asynchronously, but I have no idea how to make it work outside.

here I write console.log inside subscribe and I got the data, however, when I wrote
outside the subscribe, I received Undefined.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.Fetchdata.getData().subscribe((data) => {
          this.newUser = data;
          console.log(this.newUser) // Show all data

        });
        console.log(this.newUser) //undefined
  }
```

I appreciate any explanation or hint because I am going to lose my mind. I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing is due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript and how observables work in Angular. The code inside the `subscribe` block executes once the data is available, but code outside the `subscribe` block executes immediately after the subscription is set up, before the data arrives. This is why you're seeing `undefined` when trying to access `this.newUser` outside the `subscribe`.

To handle asynchronous data correctly, you need to perform the operations that depend on the fetched data inside the `subscribe` block or use additional mechanisms like RxJS operators or Promises. Here are a couple of approaches you can take:

#### Approach 1: Use Data Inside `subscribe`

If you need to use the fetched data immediately, you should perform the necessary operations inside the `subscribe` block:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.Fetchdata.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.newUser = data;
    console.log(this.newUser); // Data is available here

    // Perform operations using this.newUser
  });
}
```

#### Approach 2: Use RxJS Operators

RxJS provides operators that allow you to manipulate and transform observables. You can use the `map` operator to transform the data and return a new observable. This way, you can separate the data transformation from the subscription:

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.Fetchdata.getData()
    .pipe(
      map((data) => {
        this.newUser = data;
        return data; // Return the data for further processing
      })
    )
    .subscribe((transformedData) => {
      console.log(transformedData); // Data is available here
      // Perform operations using transformedData
    });
}
```

#### Approach 3: Use Promises

If you prefer working with Promises, you can convert the observable to a Promise using the `toPromise` method:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.Fetchdata.getData()
    .toPromise()
    .then((data) => {
      this.newUser = data;
      console.log(this.newUser); // Data is available here

      // Perform operations using this.newUser
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that once you convert an observable to a Promise using `toPromise`, you lose some of the benefits of observables, such as cancelation and composition, so choose this approach based on your specific use case.

Remember that JavaScript's asynchronous nature requires you to handle data availability correctly, either within the `subscribe` block or by using RxJS operators or Promises.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, was really clear and sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's because code inside subscribe isn't executed immediately. It's asynchronous, and it will execute after observable returned by getData() emits. Even if that observable emits immediately, then still code after "subscribe" block will be executed before "subscribe" itself, and you will always get undefined here.

Whatever you want to do, you have to do it inside of subscribe block. If you want to achieve something specific, give more details, I'll try to help

Comment: For example, after fetching the data I want to take this value outside the subscribe and make a condition. I don't want to use condition inside subscribe anymore, just for fetching data, and making a condition based on that result outside anywhere I need
for example: if(this.newUser) { ....... }

Comment: As the data is loaded asynchronously there is no reliable way to do that. Without further logic you won't know if the user object is falsy because it has not yet been loaded or an error occurred while loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your observable to a promise using `firstValueFrom`

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';      

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
   this.newUser = await firstValueFrom(this.Fetchdata.getData());
    
   console.log(this.newUser);
}
```